# The bugs move to each other, why it cannot work?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am writing the code of the bugs move to the next one, and the number of the bugs is "n". When t=0, the bugs are on the vertices of regular n polygon. But the code cannot work, can you help me? Thanks a lot!

```
Clear["`*"]
n = 4;
a = CirclePoints[n];
b = 0.1;
equ = Flatten[
   Append[Table[{Sqrt[
       Subscript[y, k - 1]'[t]^2 + Subscript[x, k - 1]'[t]^2] == 
       b, (Subscript[y, k][t] - Subscript[y, k - 1][t])*
        D[Subscript[x, k - 1][t], t] == 
       （Subscript[x, k][t] - Subscript[x, k - 1][t]）*
        D[Subscript[y, k - 1][t], t], 
      Subscript[y, k - 1][0] == a[[k - 1, 2]], 
      Subscript[x, k - 1][0] == a[[k - 1, 1]]}, {k, 2, 
      n}], {(Subscript[y, 1][t] - Subscript[y, n][t])*
       D[Subscript[x, n][t], 
        t] == (Subscript[x, 1][t] - Subscript[x, n][t])*
       D[Subscript[y, n][t], t], Subscript[y, n][0] == a[[n, 2]], 
     Subscript[x, n][0] == a[[n, 1]], 
     Sqrt[Subscript[y, n]'[t]^2 + Subscript[x, n]'[t]^2] == b}], 2];

sol = NDSolve[equ, 
  Flatten[{Subscript[x, #][t], Subscript[y, #][t]} & /@ Range@n, 
   2], {t, 0, 5}, MaxSteps -> 100, SolveDelayed -> True]
result = Flatten[{Subscript[x, #][t], Subscript[y, #][t]} & /@ 
    Range@n, 2];
result = Partition[result /. sol[[1]], 2];
ParametricPlot[result, {t, 0, 23}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are some weird parentheses in your code in line 10. Retype them.

```
(* Change this *)
（Subscript[x, k][t] - Subscript[x, k - 1][t]）*

(* to this *)
 (Subscript[x, k][t] - Subscript[x, k - 1][t]) *
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Nice catch, it's a full width paranthesis ）, encoded as \xEF\xBC\x89 . It is used in Japanese and Chinese, to keep them the same width as the Chinese characters. @plusPlus - make sure to use half width characters. In my Japanese input, I use F10 to switch to Romaji, which also converts all the parantheses etc to half width. Depending on your setup, you should have a similar key to convert the input.

Comment: Excellent, Thank you very much!